# newly added picklist value not available to set predefined value for a global action item

Tags: community, salesforcedx

In the Activity standard object I have a field called type which is a picklist field. I have added a new item to the list today. Also the Activity standard object doesn't have any record types as well.

How do I make this new value in type picklist field of the Activity object, available to set a predefined value in the newly created global action item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity is a special object. It's actually composed of Tasks and Events. When you create a custom field it will go on "Activity" in the object manager but record types will be configured on Task and Event. If you look there you will see record types and can add the picklist value for the specific record type you're using.

Comment: Thanks Rick, learned something new today.